# WIN DEATH error using cross walk on low memory devices

Tags: android, low-memory, crosswalk

I am working on an application on Android 4.1.1 that utilizes crosswalk in order to load a html 5 website stored locally on the device.

I am finding that the app is crashing in a couple key areas:

1. On rotation (I have disabled rotation to get around this).
2. When lots of other applications are open, it crashes when I open the application and it is loading a background image.

I have tried it with and without the Large-heap setting but that doesn't seem to effect the crashes.

The error I am getting before the crash is:
    `12-09 13:18:35.198      316-326/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{4184b318 PACKAGE.APPNAME/PACKAGE.APPNAME.MainActivity paused=false}
    12-09 13:18:35.198     316-1453/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process PACKAGE.APPNAME (pid 7534) has died.
12-09 13:18:35.222     316-1453/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force removing ActivityRecord{41640718 PACKAGE.APPNAME/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state`

Does anyone have any experience with these issues using crosswalk on low memory devices?

Thanks